# How to show a button with text in react native

Tags: react-native

suppose there is lots of text in text tag of react native , then i want to add a button at the end of this text ( more ).

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  {" "}
  <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
    {" "}
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the
    1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to
    make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also
    the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It
    was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letras{" "}
  </Text>{" "}
  <Pressable>
    {" "}
    <Text>more</Text>{" "}
  </Pressable>{" "}
</View>;
```

I can use pressable but it is a block element , i want it be inline. so that text and button can stay together.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [react-native-read-more](https://github.com/fawaz-ahmed/react-native-read-more#readme) library instead of doing on your own. However, if you want to learn how to do it. I strongly suggest that go to this library and read how it should have done it :)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap all `Text` and `Pressable` components with one top level `Text` component and everything is inlined.

```
<Text>
  <Text>
...
  </Text>
  <Pressable>
    <Text>more</Text>
  </Pressable>
  <Text>
...
  </Text>
</Text>
```